# Select GameObjects within certain distance and angle

Tags: unity-game-engine, trigonometry

So I understand the math involved, just a little confused on how to implement it. I have it grabbing the gameobjects at a certain distance already:

```
        GameObject[] nodesInView = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Node");
        List<GameObject> listOfNodesInView = new List<GameObject> ();
        foreach (GameObject node in nodesInView) {
            float dist = (player.transform.position - node.transform.position).magnitude;
            if(dist < 100)
            {
                listOfNodesInView.Add (node);
            }

        }
```

But what this is giving me is an angle of 360 degrees:

[image]

Please forgive my drawing, but it is illustrating what it is doing. But now, how would I limit the search based on an angle variable?

[image]

*EDIT Theta = value I choose, not value choose.

Also it's important to know that the red dot represents the origin, the green represents what is being collected, and the orange represents nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for gameobject within certain distance, and angle I messed around a lot and found a solution that I think works:

```
    GameObject[] nodesInView = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Node");
    List<GameObject> listOfNodesInView = new List<GameObject> ();
    foreach (GameObject node in nodesInView) {
        float dist = (player.transform.position - node.transform.position).magnitude;
        if(dist < 300)
        {
            Vector3 dir = player.transform.position - node.transform.position;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (dir.z, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            if(angle > 45 && angle < 120)
                listOfNodesInView.Add (node);
        }

    }
```

This is searching for gameobject within a certain distance AND between 2 angles. (See second picture for visual)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
// From me to another game object returns it's distance and relative angle I'd need to turn to face it
private bool CalculateDistanceAndDirectionToTarget(Transform target, out float distance, out float angle)
{
    if (target == null) { return false; }

    // distance from me
    distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);

    // angle from me
    Vector3 deltaPosition = target.position - transform.position;
    // Get the delta angle from our current forward to turn towards the target. 
    // Note: This is an absolute value and the smallest angle
    // Ref: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/376921/im-having-problems-checking-of-my-ai-can-see-me-c.html
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(deltaPosition, transform.forward);
    // To determine if we need to turn left/right, use the cross product to calculate the sign
    // Ref: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/181867/is-there-way-to-find-a-negative-angle.html
    Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(deltaPosition, transform.forward);
    if (cross.y < 0)
    {
        angle = -angle;
    }

    return true;   
}

// Determine if I can see the target given a distance and angle I can see
public bool IsWithinSight(Transform target, float maxDistance, float maxAngle)
{
    float angle = 0f;
    float distance = 0f;

     if (CalculateDistanceAndDirection(target, out distance, out angle))
     {
            if (distance < maxDistance && Mathf.Abs(angle) < maxAngle)
            {
                return true;
            }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then you can loop through all game objects of a certain type to check.